# Multisite - New User Registration Failing

Tags: wordpress, multisite

I have a Wordpress site using multisite set up and everything works as expected bar new user registration.

When I add a new user, the email gets sent as expected but then when you click on the activation link I get the following message:

***An error occurred during the activation***

***Invalid activation key.***

When I look in the wp_users table I can't see those particular users who have been sent the email as obviously the link hasn't worked.

If I set up a user and choose not to send the email then they are all showing with an 'ID' of 0 in the wp_user table.

This all worked pre-migration to a new server so I am not sure where to begin in terms of tracking down the problem.

All help is greatly appreciated.

I get the following two errors in the debug log:

```
[17-Dec-2019 12:57:38 UTC] WordPress database error Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY' for query INSERT INTO `wp_5_posts` (`post_author`, `post_date`, `post_date_gmt`, `post_content`, `post_content_filtered`, `post_title`, `post_excerpt`, `post_status`, `post_type`, `comment_status`, `ping_status`, `post_password`, `post_name`, `to_ping`, `pinged`, `post_modified`, `post_modified_gmt`, `post_parent`, `menu_order`, `post_mime_type`, `guid`) VALUES (1, '2019-12-17 12:57:38', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '', '', 'Auto Draft', '', 'auto-draft', 'post', 'open', 'open', '', '', '', '', '2019-12-17 12:57:38', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, 0, '', '') made by wp_dashboard, do_meta_boxes, wp_dashboard_quick_press, get_default_post_to_edit, wp_insert_post

[17-Dec-2019 12:58:30 UTC] WordPress database error Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY' for query INSERT INTO `wp_signups` (`domain`, `path`, `title`, `user_login`, `user_email`, `registered`, `activation_key`, `meta`) VALUES ('', '', '', '<username>', '<email address>', '2019-12-17 12:58:30', '75429b53ffc95fcd', 'a:2:{s:11:\"add_to_blog\";i:5;s:8:\"new_role\";s:10:\"subscriber\";}') made by wpmu_signup_user
```

Comment: Is there any errors in Wordpress debug.log? You can enable debug logging by editing wp-config.php and enabling these `define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);`

Comment: Hi @MariusJaraminas, please see above.

Comment: Well I don't know what plugin or template you are using for that user registration, but as you see when activation link is clicked something tries to create a user with primary ID which already exists.